# Why does such an orthogonal vector exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Suppose $W$ and $V$ are $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some
$m \geq k$. Let $V$ have orthonormal basis $\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2}, \ldots, \mathbf{v_k}$. Then is it possible to choose an orthonormal basis $\mathbf{w_1}, \mathbf{w_2}, \ldots, \mathbf{w_k}$ for $W$ such that $\mathbf{w_k}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2}, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_{k-1}$?

Comment: Check out the Gram-Schmidt process, there are other schemes that work as well but this is just one example of a method for creating basis vectors.

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC I have two different subspaces. How can you be sure it is possible to create $\mathbf{w}_k$ in this way?

Comment: Because they are of the same dimension.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: This is exactly the Gram Schmidt process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V_0$ be the span of $\mathbf{v_1},\dots,\mathbf{v}_{k-1}$ and let $P:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be the orthogonal projection onto $V_0$.  We can restrict $P$ to a linear map $W\to V_0$.  Since $\dim W=k$ and $\dim V_0=k-1$, the kernel of this linear map must be nontrivial.  Thus there is a nonzero vector $\mathbf{w}_k\in W$ (which you can scale to be a unit vector) whose projection onto $V_0$ is zero, which just means it is orthogonal to every element of $V_0$.  Extending $\mathbf{w}_k$ to an orthonormal basis of $W$, you have the desired basis.

(In fact, by iterating this construction, you can get an orthonormal basis such that $\mathbf{w}_i$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}_1,\dots,\mathbf{v}_{i-1}$ for all $i$, not just for $i=k$.  For instance, after choosing $\mathbf{w}_k$, you can let $W'$ be the orthogonal complement of $\mathbf{w}_k$ in $W$ and consider the orthogonal projection map from $W'$ to the span of $\mathbf{v_1},\dots,\mathbf{v}_{k-2}$.  Again, for dimension reasons, this projection must have nontrivial kernel, and you can let $\mathbf{w}_{k-1}$ be any unit vector in its kernel.  You can then choose $\mathbf{w}_{k-2}$ similarly, and so on.)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the right one. :) 
The other ones are misleading. :)